# How to specify background and text colors in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How I can specify a color for the background and text?

```
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Impact";
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to change `fillStyle` - it sets a color, then draw a background in color, then change color, then draw text:

```
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
ctx.font = "30px Impact";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);
```